# Check network activity in C++

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Is there any way to check if there is a network activity in the system. I don't want to send or receive the data but only want to know if there is any type of network activity going on. I know socket programming and have developed the sockets to send and receive data. Specifically, I don't want to use the network if it is already in use.

It would be great if someone can share any good resource. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to actually solve your problem, but I'm curious as to what you define as "in use". Most modern systems will use the network almost all the time, even if there's not much going on. For example, email software checks for new mails, the browser open with SO, Facebook and many others will check for "new things to show" (SO for example updates the reputation points and notifications). This happens pretty much continiously as long as the page is open. Other applications may be polling for and downloading updates, etc.

Comment: I'm not an expert on network programming, but I think you could probably use Wireshark or Snort to do what you want

Comment: Google it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/7f8644ed-3200-49c9-a491-39aec1882d75

Comment: Your question is fairly non-specific, but here's what I can show you about snooping on network activity in C++.  I recently worked on a [project](http://github.com/IronSavior/phlegethon) using libpcap in C++.  You might get some ideas from that.